# catch google map event ignoring any shapes drawn on the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I display a map (using Google Maps API) and retrieve geo-coordinates of mouse cursor using `mousemove` [event listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events). It works fine but any shape will "shield" the map, i.e. when the cursor is over the shape, the map event is not triggered anymore:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 90%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    var map0 = null;
    var defPosLat = 40.79;
    var defPosLng = -73.95;

    function initMap() {
      map0 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        zoom: 11
      });
      map0.addListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        document.getElementById("test").value = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(5) + ' ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(5);
      });
      var pCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map0,
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        radius: 10000
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <input type="text" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```

UPD. I can't set `clickable: false` because I need the shape to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need the Circle to be clickable, set `clickable: false` in the Circle options. This will allow propagation of the mouse event to the lower pane(s).

Another option obviously is to attach the same event to your Circle. See below.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 150px;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    var map0 = null;
    var defPosLat = 40.79;
    var defPosLng = -73.95;

    function initMap() {
      map0 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        zoom: 11
      });

      setMouseMove(map0);

      var pCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map0,
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        radius: 10000
      });

      setMouseMove(pCircle);
    }

    function setMouseMove(ob) {

      if (ob instanceof google.maps.Map || ob instanceof google.maps.Circle) {

        ob.addListener('mousemove', function(event) {
          document.getElementById("test").value = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(5) + ' ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(5);
        });
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <input type="text" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```

### Edit

Another option is to trigger the `mousemove` event on the map from the Circle. You still need an event listener...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 150px;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    var map0 = null;
    var defPosLat = 40.79;
    var defPosLng = -73.95;

    function initMap() {
      map0 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        zoom: 11
      });

      map0.addListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        document.getElementById("test").value = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(5) + ' ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(5);
      });

      var pCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map0,
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        radius: 10000
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(pCircle, 'mousemove', function(e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map0, 'mousemove', {
          latLng: e.latLng
        })
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <input type="text" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @MrUpsidown! Unfortunately I need the shapes to be clickable. Adding an event listener to each shape is a possible option, though ideally I'd like to avoid this (because I'll have multiple shapes, some of them created dynamically).

Comment: Added another working option which is to trigger the event from the Circle to the map. You still need an event listener. I don't see why it would be an issue to attach an event listener to all your shapes (?).

Answer (score 0):

Add `clickable: false` to your `Circle`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 90%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    var map0 = null;
    var defPosLat = 40.79;
    var defPosLng = -73.95;

    function initMap() {
      map0 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        zoom: 11
      });
      map0.addListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        document.getElementById("test").value = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(5) + ' ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(5);
      });
      var pCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map0,
        center: {
          lat: defPosLat,
          lng: defPosLng
        },
        clickable:false,
        radius: 10000
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <input type="text" id="test">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip! This would be a good workaround, but in fact I do need to catch mouse clicks on my shapes. Is there any way to still catch mousemove for the map separately? (except adding a separate event listener for each shape)

Comment: What are you using the click listener on the shape for?  Why can't you add two different ones (as in MrUpsidown's solution). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.